# Make scp skip downloading a file when "Permission denied" occure and instead try the next one

Tags: scp

After transferring 2TB of 3TB using scp my internet died. I try to resolve this matter by setting all the files I have downloaded as read only with the hope of scp trying to copy over the file, realizing that a file with that name exist and it does not have premission to overwrite it and thus skip it. However, does not work as I had hoped. Instead scp terminate, saying "Permission Denied", which is accurate but I would like it to then just give up and look at the next file.

Is this possible to do? I have not found any such flags in the manual so do not really know. Is there maybe a better way of doing it?

Comment: `rsync` is the proper tool to have a resumable download of many files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `scp` command is this shape

```
scp -rp remoteHost:/path/to/remoteDirectory localDirectory
```

You can substitute it with `rsync` to continue from where it left off

```
rsync -avP remoteHost:/path/to/remoteDirectory localDirectory
```

If you omitted the `-p` flag then the times won't have been copied and `rsync` will want to checksum the source and destination files to ensure they are the same. This will take some time - but almost certainly not nearly as much time as copying the files all over again.

Comment: Thank you very much!